# Click Event not firing on ListBoxItem ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, contextmenu, listboxitem

I'm trying to add a `ContextMenu` to `ListBoxItem`, but the `Click` event is not fired.

I  tried `ContextMenu.MenuItem.Click` event.
I also tried binding `Command`, but a binding error appears in the output window like:

> "Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Window', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=NavigateCommand;"

Here is complete sample code.

**XAML**

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu MenuItem.Click="ContextMenu_Click">
                        <MenuItem Header="Navigate"
                                  Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window, AncestorLevel=1}, Path=NavigateCommand}"
                                  Click="NavigateItemClick" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    NavigateCommand = new DelegateCommand(Navigate);
}

public DelegateCommand NavigateCommand { get; set; }


private void Navigate()
{
    MessageBox.Show("Command Worked");
}

private void NavigateItemClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Item Click Worked");
}

private void ContextMenu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Any Item click Worked");
}
```

Is there any way to invoke the `Click` event handler or bind the `Command`?

Comment: I don't think it is necessary to write "hackish" code. I think you should consider to refine your code instead.

A context menu should only work on its context, hence the name context menu. When you right click your code editor, you won't find e.g. an "Open File" menu item - this would be out of context.

The context of the menu is the actual item. Therefore, the command should be defined in the data model of the item (as the context menu should only define commands that target the items).

Comment: @BionicCode can you give me an example for correct usage. For example my listbox consists of a list of windows names that I can open. When I right click and open the relevant window , it is out of context. or can you give me an example that is not out of context

Comment: I have posted an example. You can see that the solkution is simple and intuitive. No need to "misuse"  a Tag property or define any MenuItem Styles to attach an event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ContextMenu` is not part of the same visual tree as your `ListBox`, as it is displayed in a separate window. Therefore using a `RelativeSource` or `ElementName` binding does not work *directly*. However, you can work around this issue by binding the `Window` (where you define the `NavigateCommand` in code-behind) with a `RelativeSource` binding to the [`Tag`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag?view=net-5.0) property of `ListBoxItem`. This works, since they are part of the same visual tree. The `Tag` property is a general purpose property that  you can assign anything to.

> Gets or sets an arbitrary object value that can be used to store custom information about this element.

Then use the `PlacementTarget` property of the `ContextMenu` as indirection to access the `Tag` of the `ListBoxItem` that it was opened for.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
   <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
   <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Navigate"
                      Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.NavigateCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"/>
         </ContextMenu>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

In essence, you bind the `Window` data context to the `Tag` of `ListBoxItem` which is the `PlacementTarget` of the `ContextMenu`, that can then bind the `NavigateCommand` through the `Tag` property.

Adding a `Click` event handler is also possible, but in case the `ContextMenu` is defined in a `Style`, you have to add it differently, otherwise it will not work and you get this strange exception.

> Unable to cast object of type `System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem` to type `System.Windows.Controls.Button`.

Add a `MenuItem` style with an event setter for `Click`, where you assign the event handler.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
   <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Navigate">
               <MenuItem.Style>
                  <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                     <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="MenuItem_OnClick"/>
                  </Style>
               </MenuItem.Style>
            </MenuItem>
         </ContextMenu>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. I have one more question. Assuming we don't use DataContext, let's say we just write code with codebehind so I want to bind the window itself to the tag property, not the DataContext. how can I do that

Comment: @ErhanUrun I already edited the code. Before, the binding was `{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}` which binds the `DataContext` of the `Window`. Now it is `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}` which binds the `Window` itself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is necessary to write "hackish" code. I think you should refine your code instead.

A context menu should only operate on its current UI context, hence the name context menu. When you right click your code editor, you won't find e.g. an "Open File" menu item - this would be out of context.

The context of the menu is the actual item. Therefore, the command should be defined in the data model of the item as the context menu should only define commands that target the items.

Note that the `ContextMenu` is always implicitly hosted inside a `Popup` (as `Child` of `Popup`). The child elements of `Popup` can never part of the visual tree (since the content is rendered inside a dedicated `Window` instance and `Window` can't be a child of another element, `Window` is always the root of its own visual tree), therefore tree traversal using `Binding.RelativeSource` can't work.
You can reference `ContextMenu.PlacementTarget` (instead of `DataContext`) to get the actual `ListBoxItem` (the placement target). The `DataContext` of the `ListBoxItem` is the data model (WindowItem class in the example below).

For example to reference the e.g. `OpenWindowCommand` of the underlying data model of the current `ListBoxItem` from inside the `ContextMenu` use:

```
"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext.OpenWindowCommand}"
```

**WindowItem.cs**
Create a data model for the items in the list. This data model exposes all the commands to operate on the item itself.

```
class WindowItem
{
  public WindowItem(string windowName) => this.Name = windowName;

  public string Name { get; }

  public ICommand OpenWindowCommand => new RelayCommand(ExecuteOpenWindow);

  private void ExecuteOpenWindow(object commandParameter)
  {
    // TODO::Open the window associated with this instance
    MessageBox.Show($"Window {this.Name} is open");
  }

  public override string ToString() => this.Name;
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**
Initialize the ListBox from your MainWindow using data binding:

```
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public ObservableCollection<WindowItem> WindowItems { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;

    var windowItems = new 
    this.WindowItems = new ObservableCollection<WindowItem> 
    {
      new WindowItem { Name = "Window 1" },
      new WindowItem { Name = "Window 2" }
    }
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>

    <!-- Command version -->
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ListBoxItemContextMenu">
      <MenuItem Header="Open"
                Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext.OpenWindowCommand}" />
    </ContextMenu>

    <!-- Optionally define a Click handler in code-behind (MainWindow.xaml.cs) -->
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ListBoxItemContextMenu">
      <MenuItem Header="Open"
                Click="OpenWindow_OnMenuItemClick" />
    </ContextMenu>
  </Window.Resources>

  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding WindowItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ListBoxItemContextMenu}">
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  </ListBox>
</Window>
```